# Plotly Express Choropleth as go.Figure with Dropdown and Slider

Tags: plotly, plotly-express

I'm trying to make a choropleth with a drop down and a slider for years.  I read that this would need to be done as a `graph_object` rather than express.  Using the `px.choropleth` by itself renders the map correctly:

```
allfig = px.choropleth(
    geojson='geojson-counties-fips.json', 
    data_frame=maxindustry,
    locations=maxindustry['GeoFIPS'],
    locationmode='geojson-id',
    scope='usa',
    color=maxindustry['Description'],
    animation_frame=maxindustry['Year'],
    # animation_group=maxindustry['Description'],
    hover_name=maxindustry['GeoName']
    )
allfig.show()
```

[image]
When I wrapped the express figures into a `graph_objects` figure, the map doesn't render at all.

```
allfig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    geojson='geojson-counties-fips.json', 
    data_frame=maxindustry,
    locations=maxindustry['GeoFIPS'],
    # locationmode='geojson-id',
    # scope='usa',
    color=maxindustry['Description'],
    animation_frame=maxindustry['Year'],
    # animation_group=maxindustry['Description'],
    hover_name=maxindustry['GeoName']
    )

goodsfig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    geojson='geojson-counties-fips.json',
    data_frame=goodsprod,
    locations=goodsprod.GeoFIPS,
    # locationmode='geojson-id',
    # scope='usa',
    color=goodsprod['Description'],
    animation_frame=goodsprod['Year'],
)

servsfig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    geojson='geojson-counties-fips.json',
    data_frame=servprod,
    locations=servprod.GeoFIPS,
    # locationmode='geojson-id',
    # scope='usa',
    color=servprod['Description'],
    animation_frame=servprod['Year'],
)

service = dict(method= 'update',
               label='Services Producing',
               args=[
                    {"color": [servprod['Description']],
                    "hovertemplate": "County: %{servprod[2]}%<br>"+\
                                      "Highest GDP-Contributing Industry: %{servprod[3]}%<extra></extra>",
                    "visible": [True, False]
                    }, #dict for fig.data[0] updates
                    {"title":"Services Producing" } #dict for  layout attribute update 
                 ])

goods = dict(method= 'update',
               label='Goods Producing',
               args=[
                   {"color": [goodsprod['Description']],
                    "hovertemplate": "County: %{goodsprod[2]}%<br>"+\
                                      "Highest GDP-Contributing Industry: %{goodsprod[3]}%<extra></extra>",
                    "visible": [False, True]
                   },
                   {"title":"Goods Producing"} #update layout attribute    
           ])
both = dict(method= 'update',
               label='Goods and Services',
               args=[
                   {"color": [maxindustry['Description']],
                    "hovertemplate": "County: %{maxindustry[1]}%<br>"+\
                                      "Highest GDP-Contributing Industry: %{maxindustry[6]}%<extra></extra>",
                    "visible": [True, True]
                   },
                   {"title":"Goods and Services"} #update layout attribute    
           ])

buttons = [both, goods, service]
updatemenus = [{'active':0, "showactive": True, "buttons":buttons}]

fig = go.Figure(layout=dict(updatemenus=updatemenus))
fig.add_traces(allfig.data)
fig.update_layout(title=title )
fig.show()
```

[image]
In `add_traces` I tried using a list of `[allfig.data, goodsfig.data, servsfig.data]` but same thing happens.  `go.Figure()` doesn't accept `px.choropleth`, only `px.choropleth_mapbox`.

For reference, `goodsprod` and `servprod` are

```
servprod = maxindustry.loc[maxindustry['Parent'].isin({'Private services-producing', 'Trade',
       'Transportation and utilities',
       'Educational services, health care, and social assistance',
       'Arts, entertainment, recreation, accommodation, and food services','Finance, insurance, real estate, rental, and leasing',
       'Professional and business services'}), ['GeoFIPS', 'GeoName', 'Year', 'Description']]
goodsprod = maxindustry.loc[maxindustry['Parent'].isin({'Private goods-producing', 'Natural resources and mining'}), ['GeoFIPS', 'GeoName', 'Year', 'Description']]
```